# MySQL - 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-error-1111

I'm getting an error of group function while trying to get the volatage stability per hour.
table as an image below.
[table-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko26U.png)

```
SELECT  ip, 
        SUM(CASE HOUR(time) WHEN '1' THEN CAST(AVG(IF(volt=0,0,1)) AS DECIMAL(2,1)) ELSE 0 END) AS '1',
        SUM(CASE HOUR(time) WHEN '2' THEN CAST(AVG(IF(volt=0,0,1)) AS DECIMAL(2,1)) ELSE 0 END) AS '2',
        SUM(CASE HOUR(time) WHEN '3' THEN CAST(AVG(IF(volt=0,0,1)) AS DECIMAL(2,1)) ELSE 0 END) AS '3'
FROM UPS_Status
WHERE time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 24 hour AND NOW()
GROUP BY ip, HOUR(time)
```

Comment: You create `SUM( .. AVG() .. )` expression - aggregate within aggregate. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HOUR(time)` does not belong in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Try removing it:

```sql
SELECT 
    ip, 
    SUM(CASE HOUR(time) WHEN 1 THEN CAST(IF(volt=0, 0, 1) AS DECIMAL(2,1)) ELSE 0 END) AS `1`,
    SUM(CASE HOUR(time) WHEN 2 THEN CAST(IF(volt=0, 0, 1) AS DECIMAL(2,1)) ELSE 0 END) AS `2`,
    SUM(CASE HOUR(time) WHEN 3 THEN CAST(IF(volt=0, 0, 1) AS DECIMAL(2,1)) ELSE 0 END) AS `3`
FROM UPS_Status
WHERE 
    time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 24 hour AND NOW()
GROUP BY ip;
```

Comment: ```.. CAST(SUM(HOUR(time)=1 AND volt<>0) AS DECIMAL(2,1)) AS `1`, ..``` produces the same output but needs less work.

Comment: Agree, but I would really also like to see sample data.  This answer is just enough to perhaps run without syntax error, but not more.

Comment: thanks, that worked, but a bit confusing. but why is AVG()  skipped? i mean,  i get 12 records from ip per hour, and get the average.

Comment: Not sure what your intended logic is, but using `AVG()` inside `SUM()` does not make much sense.

Comment: Stupid me. Thank you Tim. Thank you Akina.